# Why does Watson call Moriarty the "Napoleon of Crime"?

Tags: analysis, dialogue, seven-per-cent-solution

At the end of [*The Seven-Per-Cent Solution*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075194/) we learn that *Holmes*'s obsession with *Moriarty* comes from his suppressed childhood memory of *Moriarty*'s affair with *Holmes*'s mother when he was his teacher (after which *Holmes*'s father killed his mother). But after learning this, *Watson* says to *Freud*:

> The Napoleon of Crime. Holmes was right about him from the very
>   beginning, Professor Moriarty I mean.

Referencing the nickname *Holmes* gave *Moriarty* earlier, when he thought him to be a criminal mastermind. But what does he mean with this statement, given that *Moriarty* was *not* the criminal genius that *Holmes* made out of him, but just a timid little mathematics teacher that had an affair with his mother. So he wasn't *"right about him from the very beginning*". Is he merely saying that this was as heavy a crime (especially given that it lead to *Holmes*'s mother getting killed), or does he mean something else with this line (maybe in reference to the real *Napoleon*)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Napoleon Bonaparte was a [notorious](http://www.authorama.com/famous-affinities-of-history-ii-6.html) womanizer, and his [antics](http://williamdietrich.com/napoleon-and-sex/) have been recorded in numerous [books](http://www.archive.org/stream/loveaffairsofnap00turq/loveaffairsofnap00turq_djvu.txt) and [documentaries](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5f-NtY2qzM).

According to '[Napoleon and his Women](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Napoleon-Wives-Women-Christopher-Hibbert/dp/0006531466)', by British historian Christopher Hibbert, Napoleon would often weaponize his sexual experiences for leverage and political power, making him effectively a gigolo, although its a stretch to apply this handle to the Emperor.

Even though Napoleon existed in the time before tabloid journalism, court gossip was powerful enough to consolidate this reputation internationally, and it could well be this that Watson is referring to.